# ProgressBar Marquee not animaged

Tags: c#, .net-core, progress-bar

I am moving code from .net framework to .net core, and am having issues with the `ProgressBar` in marquee mode not animating.

With the below code, the progress bar does not move.

```
        LoadProgressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
        LoadProgressBar.Visible = true;
        int loop = 1;
        for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
```

When I add a Refresh, the progress bar moves.

```
        LoadProgressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
        LoadProgressBar.Visible = true;
        int loop = 1;
        for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            Refresh();
        }
```

I'm actually calling a method that checks a SQL connection, which can take a while if the database cannot be accessed, but calling `Refresh` multiple times after the method finishes is a bit ridiculous. Also, setting up a timer just to call refresh over and over seems like a bad choice, especially when this works with no problems without calling `Refresh` in Framework.

I also tested in Continuous mode, calling `PerformStep`, which animates properly. It is just Marquee without multiple refreshes that doesn't work. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

As a side note, I do call `Application.EnableVisualStyles();` in my constructor.

Comment: Don't _Sleeping_ the UI thread. That what prevents the controls from being refreshed. Check the SQL connection in another thread. Use `async/await` pattern.

Comment: Add `async` keyword to a method signature like `private async void button_Click`. Then change `Thread.Sleep(100)` to `await Task.Delay(100)`. No need to `Refresh()`, remove it. [Asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async).

Comment: That was the solution. I made the method async. It required changing up the method line, but the progress bar works now. Thank you for the feedback.